# Create single columns - Auto width for using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want a single column bootstrap grid where as it will have n number of divs to place inside horizontally(max 6 divs). The width of the div should be auto aligned
How to do this ?.

```
<div class="well relevantBox">
    <div class="col-sm-auto col-xs-auto vcenter">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up boxIconStyle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-auto col-xs-auto"><span class="pull-right">{{RelevantCount}}</span></div>

</div>
```

Currently when i tried to do, each div occupying full width of the container then the next div is placing it to the second line.

Answer (score -1):

As i understood like this way you need **[This a DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/kduw1n6g/)**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="col-md-8 a"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 b"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 c"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 d"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 e"></div>
<div class="col-md-8 f"></div>
</div>
```